# fix the version conflict either by updating the version of the google-services plugin

Tags: android, android-gradle-plugin, firebase-cloud-messaging, google-places-api, google-play-services

I am using Google's Firebase (For notification) and Places (For address and location) API in my project. Latest version of both are 16.0.6 and 16.0.0 respectively that I am using in app.

When integrating either api, app is working fine. But on integrating together it gives below error:

> Execution failed for task ':app:processDebugGoogleServices'.
>
> Please fix the version conflict either by updating the version of the google-services plugin (information about the latest version is available at https://bintray.com/android/android-tools/com.google.gms.google-services/) or updating the version of com.google.android.gms to 16.0.6.

I checked other posts too, but they are old now and not helping me.

Below is my app module's `build.gradle`

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'

buildscript {
    repositories {
        google()
        mavenCentral()
        maven { url 'https://maven.fabric.io/public' }
        maven {
            url "https://maven.google.com"
        }

    }
    dependencies {
        // replace with the current version of the Android plugin
        classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:3.2.1'
        classpath 'com.google.gms:google-services:3.1.1'
    }
}

android {
    compileSdkVersion 26
    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "abc.xyz"
        minSdkVersion 19
        targetSdkVersion 26
        versionCode 1
        versionName "1.0"
        testInstrumentationRunner "android.support.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"
        multiDexEnabled true

        // add below section
        javaCompileOptions {
            annotationProcessorOptions {
                includeCompileClasspath true
            }
        }
    }
    buildTypes {
        debug {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
            debuggable true
            signingConfig signingConfigs.Release
            zipAlignEnabled true
        }
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
            debuggable false
            signingConfig signingConfigs.Release
            zipAlignEnabled true
        }
    }
}

repositories {
    maven { url 'https://oss.sonatype.org/content/repositories/snapshots' }
}

configurations {
    all*.exclude group: 'com.android.support', module: 'support-v13'
}

dependencies {
    implementation fileTree(include: ['*.jar'], dir: 'libs')
    implementation 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:26.1.0'

    //LinkedIn SDK
    implementation project(':linkedin-sdk')
    implementation 'com.github.bumptech.glide:glide:3.8.0'
    implementation 'com.ethanhua:skeleton:1.1.2'
    implementation 'io.supercharge:shimmerlayout:2.1.0'
    implementation 'com.android.support.constraint:constraint-layout:1.1.2'
    testImplementation 'junit:junit:4.12'
    implementation 'com.google.code.gson:gson:2.8.2'
    implementation 'com.android.support:design:26.1.0'
    implementation 'com.android.support:recyclerview-v7:26.1.0'
    implementation 'com.facebook.android:facebook-android-sdk:4.34.0'
    implementation 'com.google.code.gson:gson:2.8.2'
    implementation 'de.hdodenhof:circleimageview:2.1.0'
    implementation 'org.androidannotations:androidannotations-api:4.3.1'

    <!-- Google apis -->
    implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-core:16.0.6'
    implementation 'com.google.android.gms:play-services:12.0.1'
    implementation 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-places:16.0.0'

    annotationProcessor 'org.androidannotations:androidannotations:4.3.1'
}

apply plugin: 'com.google.gms.google-services'
```

Is there any otherway I can work with both?

Answer (score 0):

I could not figure out what is wrong here. But i tried downgrading version number to 12.0.1 of both libraries and it worked fine.